# logging in with selenium python is failing. but no issues when trying manually

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webautomation

I tried to login to https://einvoice1.gst.gov.in/ with selenium but it is not acting consistently, 80% of the time it fails with 400 error even after using wait of up-to 4 sec after every action.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options = options)
browser.set_window_size(1900, 1200)
browser.implicitly_wait(4)
browser.get('https://einvoice1.gst.gov.in')

browser.find_element_by_id('btnLogin').click() # opening login window (same page)
browser.find_element_by_id('txtUserName').send_keys(username) 
browser.find_element_by_id('txt_password').send_keys(password)
# waiting for few seconds to enter Captcha
browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')[2].click() # submit form
```

Response:
HTTP Error 400

Comment: Apply external wait on element on every page load or any event trigger.

Comment: Tried long waits between individual actions, tried random waits no use.

Comment: This should send the keys to your elements.

Comment: add from time import sleep and give some sleep time for captcha solving something like sleep(60)

Comment: 400 server error? I don't see how waits will help with that. Check the network panel when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Apply waits on elements and click on login prior to entering. There is a captchacode I don't know how to handle. You might need to input for that.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnLogin"))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "txtUserName"))).send_keys(username)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "txt_password"))).send_keys(password)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "CaptchaCode"))).send_keys('5')
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"LoginButton"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```